# Read dates from excel to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have .xlsx excel file, which one of its column shows the dates (the first 6 rows are shown as below):

```
Recd_Date/Due_Date
01/31/2000
02/29/2000
02/01/2000
03/01/2000
02/02/2000
03/02/2000
```

After I used Pandas' read_excel() to convert the excel to pandas Dataframe, the 'Recd_Date/Due_Date' is shown as:

```
Recd_Date/Due_Date
2000-01-31 00:00:00
2000-02-29 00:00:00
2000-01-02 00:00:00
2000-01-03 00:00:00
2000-02-02 00:00:00
2000-02-03 00:00:00

type(df.ix[i]['Recd_Date/Due_Date']) = pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

As you can see read_excel() got some of the dates wrong, e.g. 02/01/2000 becomes 2000-01-02 00:00:00 (it should be 2000-02-01 00:00:00); 03/02/2000 becomes 2000-02-03 00:00:00 ( should be 2000-03-02 00:00:00)...How can i make it understand the dates in the original excel file as month/day/year and so it can convert the dates correctly??

Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you post an example Excel file that fails?  If I copy/paste your example data into a clean file it parses correctly.

Comment: Where are you physically located, and what locale settings are configured on your machine?  It looks like your machine is set to expect D/M/Y dates as used in Europe whereas your file is M/D/Y as in the US.  Of course Pandas can see that 01/31/2000 is M/D/Y because D/M/Y would give month=31....

Comment: You're quite right! I am located in the UK, and my machine is set to expect D/M/Y dates. But I just changed it to expect M/D/Y dates and Pandas still gives the wrong dates...

Comment: First - I don't think it's pandas's fault at all. The problem is either in excel or specifically defined in the file. pandas is probably using excel and gets the dates it's getting. So if you're 100% sure you correctly changed the regional setting in your pc - it's probably specifically defined in the xls file (the column type is date, and the format is manually defined).

Comment: Have to looked at pandas.to_datetime function? Try explicitly setting the dayfirst argument as false

Answer (score 0):

Why not create another column with the date inverted ? You can transform the code below into a function and use it.

```
data = '01/31/2000'
data2 = data.split("/")
data22 = []
for i in range(-1, -4, -1):
    data22.append(data2[i]) 

data3 = "/".join(data22)
```